# PHPUnit mocked property not able to mock chained function

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm working with the Stripe API in Laravel and am trying to mock the `retrieve` function in the customers part of the api.

I am `retrieve` in my code below:

`$customer = $this->stripe->customers->retrieve($event->item->stripe_id);`

In my test I have the following mocking:

```
$stripeMock = Mockery::mock(Stripe::class);
$stripeMock->shouldReceive('setApiKey')->once();
$stripeMock->shouldReceive('retrieve')->once()->andReturn([]);
$stripeMock->customers = '';
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function retrieve() on string
```

If I remove the line where I set the `customers` property however I get this error:

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: Mockery_0_Stripe_Stripe::$customers
```

Suggestions on how I can set the `customers` property and still be able to return a mocked response

Comment: But, how can you access `customers`'s `retrieve` method if `customers` is a string ?

Comment: What type of object is `customers` ? You have to Mock that also.

Comment: It's an object returned by stripe